# How Come this MOVSB Assembly Language Code Works?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I cannot for the life of me understand why the below IA-32 assembly code works. I will explain the part I do not understand by walking through the code, line by line, below.

```
section .text
   global main
main:
   mov ecx, len
   mov esi, s1
   mov edi, s2
   cld
   rep movsb
   mov edx,20 ;message length
   mov ecx,s2 ;message to write
   mov ebx,1 ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov eax,4 ;system call number (sys_write)
   int 0x80 ;call kernel
   mov eax,1 ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int 0x80 ;call kernel
section .data
   s1 db 'Hello, world!', 0
   len equ $-s1
section .bss
   s2 resb 20
```

First, ecx is set to the length of the string so that the rep will repeat movsb for all the characters in the string. Next, esi is set to equal the string and edi is set to be 20 bytes. Next, we clear the direction flag so that movsb copies in the right direction. Finally, we get to the movsb mnemonic which will move a character from the memory address specified in esi to the memory address specified in edi. That is repeated for each character in the string.

The problem I have is that if you look at esi and edi, they are NOT set to be the address of s1 and s2. They are set to be the value of s1 and s2. If we wanted to set the registers to be the address, i thought we would have to use "mov esi, [s1]" and "mov edi, [s2]". That however, is not what the code says. The code is from a tutorial to assembly programming, so should be right.

Thanks a lot for helping me get to the bottom of this.

Magnus

Comment: No.  I'm guessing the debugger is just confusing you, showing you the memory content at edi instead of the register value.

Comment: There is no debugger or anything. The code above is from a tutorial I am reading. I am trying to understand why it is correct as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem I have is that if you look at esi and edi, they are NOT set to be the address of s1 and s2. They are set to be the value of s1 and s2. If we wanted to set the registers to be the address, i thought we would have to use "mov esi, [s1]" and "mov edi, [s2]".

You've got it backwards.
`mov esi,foo` is what you'd use to put the address of `foo` into `esi`, and `mov esi,[foo]` is what you'd use to put the value located at the address of `foo` into `esi`.

Note that the syntax differs between different assemblers. What I said above is true for NASM (which is what you've indicated that you're using), but when using MASM/TASM you'd use `mov esi,OFFSET foo` to get the address, while `mov esi,foo` and `mov esi,[foo]` both would get the value.

Comment: Is that right for sure? Oh man, if so I have missed something really basic. So "mov [eax], var1" means put the address of var1 (say 0x0040120e) into what eax points to?

Comment: Right (in NASM syntax). Actually it'd probably be `mov dword [eax],var1`.

Comment: Sorry for breaking the rules by using the comment field for a thank you message, but thank you Michael, you are awesome.

Comment: Final question: If I do "mov eax, 5" "mov ebx, eax". Following your explanation above, will now ebx contain the address of the eax register (say 0x0040120e), as opposed to the value 5?

Comment: Another quick question (@Michael): In my tutorial they use this example for indirect memory addressing: "my_table times 10 DW 0" "Mov ebx, [my_table]". They say that ebx now contains the effective address of my_table. That seems to break with what you said, no? I mean, according to that ebx should now contain the value of my_table in memory (as we used brackets), not the address. They define effective address as the offset value needed to combine with the segment start address to find the exact location of data in memory.

Comment: Are you sure that's a `mov` and not `lea`? The way they describe it makes it sound like it's a `lea`.

Comment: Yes. Bottom of page 29, here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_tutorial.pdf . Tried to figure it out, but still stuck. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd say the tutorial is wrong. It should be either `mov ebx,MY_TABLE` or `lea ebx,[MY_TABLE]`

Comment: I would agree. That guide is full of examples that seems to be incorrect, and the text is too high-level. Leaves more questions than answers. Another thing that looks like a mistake: In the same example (bottom of page 29), I am pretty sure adding 2 would mean we get my_table[2]=123 (as opposed to my_table[1]).